# How do I to get the three dots on slideshow clickable to show the corresponding slide?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I to get the three dots on slideshow clickable to show the corresponding slide?

Im wanting the three dots along the bottom of the carousel to be clickable so it shows the corresponding slide. How do i achieve this using jQuery?

Someone recommended getting the index of the current slide and then using the index to apply a class to the correct dot...but im not sure how to go about this.

http://slideshow-test-22.superhi.com/

```js
var currentSlide = 0
var totalSlides = $('.holder div.slide').length

var moveSlide = function(slide) {
  var leftPosition = -(slide * 100) + 'vw'
  $('.holder').css('left', leftPosition)
}

// Next Slide Function
var nextSlide = function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1
  if (currentSlide >= totalSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

// Previous Slide Function
var previousSlide = function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1
  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = totalSlides - 1
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

// Auto Slide Function
var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide()
}, 5000)

// Arrows Function
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  nextSlide()
})

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  previousSlide()
})
```

```css
/* Base Carousel Styling */

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10000vw;
  height: 550px;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.holder div.slide {
  float: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
}

.slide {
  background-color: #f1f1f2;
  position: relative;
}

a.prev,
a.next {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.prev {
  left: 10px;
}

.next {
  right: 10px;
}


/* End Of Base Carousel Styling */


/*Slide Styling*/

.slide {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*Slide Copy + CTA Styling*/

h1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}


/*  p{
         font-family: Open Sans;
         font-size:18px;
         line-height: 1.2;
          text-transform: capitalize;
}

 a.cta{
         font-family: Open Sans;
         font-size:12px;
         line-height: 1.2;
         padding:16px 8px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
} */

.copy-cta-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*Slide One Styling*/

.slide-1 {
  background-color: #101820;
}

.slide-2 {
  background-color: #283c50;
}

.slide-3 {
  background-color: #426385;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.carousel-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="slide-1 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-2 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-3 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">&gt;</a>
  <section class="carousel-dots">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of your existing "moveSlide" function to make it work. You just need to supply it with the correct slide index.

I made a version which use jQuery syntax (as requested) to handle clicks on the dots. It uses a data-attribute embedded in each dot element to know which slide to target.

HTML:

```
<section class="carousel-dots">
  <span class="dot" data-slide="0"></span>
  <span class="dot" data-slide="1"></span>
  <span class="dot" data-slide="2"></span>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".dot").click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  moveSlide($(this).data("slide"));
});
```

Demo:

```js
var currentSlide = 0
var totalSlides = $('.holder div.slide').length

var moveSlide = function(slide) {
  var leftPosition = -(slide * 100) + 'vw'
  $('.holder').css('left', leftPosition)
}

// Next Slide Function
var nextSlide = function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1
  if (currentSlide >= totalSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

// Previous Slide Function
var previousSlide = function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1
  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = totalSlides - 1
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

// Auto Slide Function
var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide()
}, 5000)

// Arrows Function
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  nextSlide()
})

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  previousSlide()
})

$(".dot").click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  moveSlide($(this).data("slide"));
});
```

```css
/* Base Carousel Styling */

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10000vw;
  height: 550px;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.holder div.slide {
  float: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
}

.slide {
  background-color: #f1f1f2;
  position: relative;
}

a.prev,
a.next {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.prev {
  left: 10px;
}

.next {
  right: 10px;
}


/* End Of Base Carousel Styling */


/*Slide Styling*/

.slide {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*Slide Copy + CTA Styling*/

h1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}


/*  p{
         font-family: Open Sans;
         font-size:18px;
         line-height: 1.2;
          text-transform: capitalize;
}

 a.cta{
         font-family: Open Sans;
         font-size:12px;
         line-height: 1.2;
         padding:16px 8px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
} */

.copy-cta-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*Slide One Styling*/

.slide-1 {
  background-color: #101820;
}

.slide-2 {
  background-color: #283c50;
}

.slide-3 {
  background-color: #426385;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.carousel-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="slide-1 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-2 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-3 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">&gt;</a>
  <section class="carousel-dots">
    <span class="dot" data-slide="0"></span>
    <span class="dot" data-slide="1"></span>
    <span class="dot" data-slide="2"></span>
  </section>
</div>
```

N.B. Your previous code wasn't far off (even if it was using inline event handlers), it just a) called the wrong function name, and b) the slide indexes were out by 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the existing `moveSlide()` function to change the active slide. All you need to do is relate the index of the clicked `.dot` element to the slide, which can be done by getting its `index()`. Try this:

```
$('.dot').click(function() {
  currentSlide = $(this).index();
  moveSlide(currentSlide);
});
```

Complete example:

```js
var currentSlide = 0
var totalSlides = $('.holder div.slide').length

$('.dot').click(function() {
  currentSlide = $(this).index();
  moveSlide(currentSlide);
});

var moveSlide = function(slide) {
  var leftPosition = -(slide * 100) + 'vw'
  $('.holder').css('left', leftPosition)
}

// Next Slide Function
var nextSlide = function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1
  if (currentSlide >= totalSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

// Previous Slide Function
var previousSlide = function() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1
  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = totalSlides - 1
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

// Auto Slide Function
var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide()
}, 5000)

// Arrows Function
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  nextSlide()
})

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  previousSlide()
})
```

```css
/* Base Carousel Styling */

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10000vw;
  height: 550px;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.holder div.slide {
  float: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
}

.slide {
  background-color: #f1f1f2;
  position: relative;
}

a.prev,
a.next {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.prev {
  left: 10px;
}

.next {
  right: 10px;
}


/* End Of Base Carousel Styling */


/*Slide Styling*/

.slide {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*Slide Copy + CTA Styling*/

h1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}


/*  p{
         font-family: Open Sans;
         font-size:18px;
         line-height: 1.2;
          text-transform: capitalize;
}

 a.cta{
         font-family: Open Sans;
         font-size:12px;
         line-height: 1.2;
         padding:16px 8px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
} */

.copy-cta-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*Slide One Styling*/

.slide-1 {
  background-color: #101820;
}

.slide-2 {
  background-color: #283c50;
}

.slide-3 {
  background-color: #426385;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.carousel-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="slide-1 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-2 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-3 slide">
      <div class="copy-cta-container">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">&gt;</a>
  <section class="carousel-dots">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.